# How do i fix my list to allow it to check one letter at a time?

Tags: c#, string, char, listbox

i am on the c# basics and i require to create a spelling test/hangman where the user will enter the word and it will be checked per letter if it has matched with the secret word. i have created a for loop to check the word but an error appears saying that it can only be on letter as of course it is a char? is there any way o fix this?

```
     public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


               string[] listwords = new string[10];
        listwords[0] = "jungle";
        listwords[1] = "forest";
        listwords[2] = "horse";
        listwords[3] = "beetle";
        listwords[4] = "nature";
        listwords[5] = "monkey";
        listwords[6] = "autumn";
        listwords[7] = "spring";
        listwords[8] = "flower";
        listwords[9] = "birds";

        Random randGen = new Random();
        var idx = randGen.Next(0, 9);
        string guessWord = listwords[idx];
        char[] guess = new char[guessWord.Length];
        Console.Write("please enter your guess : ");

        for (int i = 0; i < guessWord.Length; i++)
            guess[i] = '*';

        while (true)
        {
            char userGuess = char.Parse(txtGuess.Text);
            for (int i = 0; i < guessWord.Length; i++)
            {

                if (userGuess == guessWord[i])
                    guess[i] = userGuess;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `txtGuess` ?

Comment: You're confusing a Console app with a WinForms app. You cannot have that `while (true)` loop in the Form's Constructor. The GUI won't even show up. Fix that before anything else. Or make a console app instead.

Answer (score 0):

Some tips:

```
//all this
char[] guess = new char[guessWord.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < guessWord.Length; i++)
        guess[i] = '*';


//can be replaced with
char[] guess = new string('*', guessWord.Length).ToCharArray();
```

---

```
//this fails if .Text is not a string of length 1
char userGuess = char.Parse(txtGuess.Text);

//consider this:
char userGuess = (txtGuess.Text + '*')[0];
```

Strings can be indexed like they're arrays. `"Hello world"[3]` is the char `l`. Adding a `*` to the end of the text and taking the first char `[0]` is relatively robust; it'll always have a length of at least 1, and if the user doesn't enter anything then the action is a no-op (replace * with *)

---

That code you had in the constructor, in the while loop, should be put in a button click handler. Add a button to your form, double click it and put the code in there instead. Do not have an infinite loop in a constructor.

Your `string guessWord` and `char[] guess` should be class level properties/fields so that their state is remembered between button clicks